# What is the difference between merge and replace in ADF copy activity insert type for table storage dataset

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage

What is the difference between merge/replace/dynamic content for insert type option in ADF copy activity for table storage datasets

Answer (score 0):

Both the Merge and the Replace options do `upsert` operation only. The difference could be in the way they process the input data and transfer to sink. Merge updates the value in the sink if the `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` value matches with the source entity. Otherwise, it inserts the new entity from source to sink. Similarly, `Replace` replaces the entire entity with the values in the source when matched with `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` of source. Otherwise, inserts the entity in sink.

[image: img]

Comment: Thanks for the detail.So basically both are same right? What about dynamic content?

Comment: Dynamic content gives a way to create dynamic expressions that can be used to define values for properties in a flexible and reusable way. For example, if the mode of insert will be dynamic like it depends on other dataset, then you can use Add dynamic content. Here, I tried to [assign the value as merge in variable](https://i.imgur.com/QmbhJsC.png) and then used that variable in [Add dynamic content of InsertType](https://i.imgur.com/tu2yYwe.png).